# How to hide QComboBox items instead of clearing them out

Tags: python, pyqt

I can't find a way to hide `QComboBox` items. So far the only way to filter its items out is to delete the existing ones (with `.clear()` method). And then to rebuild the entire `QComboBox` again using its `.addItem()` method.

I would rather temporary hide the items. And when they are needed to unhide them back.
Is hide/unhide on QCombobox items could be accomplished?

Comment: You talking about '.addItem()' ? This is in 'QListWidget' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `removeItem()` method to remove an item from the `QComboBox`.

> void QComboBox::removeItem ( int index )
>
> Removes the item at the given index from the combobox. This will update the current index if the index is removed.
>
> This function does nothing if index is out of range.

If you don't know the index, use the `findText()` method.

There are no hide/unhide methods for `QComboBox` items.

Comment: If he's looking to "hide" a single item in the combo box it's best to just remove it and then add it later when it's necessary.

Comment: It's about hiding an entry, not about removing it … see the answer below on how to do it (qobject_cast<QListView *>(combobox->view())->setRowHidden(0, true);)

Answer (score 14):

In case someone still looking for an answer:

By default, `QComboBox` uses `QListView` to display the popup list and `QListView` has the `setRowHidden()` method:

```
qobject_cast<QListView *>(comboBox->view())->setRowHidden(0, true);
```

Edit: fix code according to @Tobias Leupold's comment.
Edit: Python version:

```py
# hide row
view = comboBox.view()
view.setRowHidden(row, True)

# disable item
model = comboBox.model()
item = model.item(row)
item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

# enable item
view.setRowHidden(row, false)
item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

Comment: I had to cast the view in the following way: qobject_cast<QListView *>(comboBox->view())->setRowHidden(0, true); Actually, this one should be the accepted answer!

Comment: --There's another caveat with this method^ while the item will be invisible and not available for mouse clicks, it will still be accessible with the scroll wheel and the keyboard.-- Should have read the whole thread again before commenting =)

Comment: You're right, thanks for poining out that the item also has to be disabled to prevent wheel and arrow keys selection!

Comment: Adding to an old thread, there is another case to handle. If the currentIndex already points to the hidden item, it is still visible until the index changes. PyQt5. I wrote a function to locate an item that is still visible, and set the index to that.

Answer (score 8):

To build on what @kef answered:

(excuse the C++ on the python question)

By default the QComboBox will use a QListView for the view, thus you can do the following:

```
QListView* view = qobject_cast<QListView *>(combo->view());
Q_ASSERT(view != nullptr);
view->setRowHidden(row, true);
```

The one drawback with the above is, that even though the item will be hidden from the popup, the user can still select it using the mouse wheel. To overcome this add the following for the hidden row:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(combo->model());
Q_ASSERT(model != nullptr);
QStandardItem* item = model->item(row);
item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
```

With the above the row will be hidden and the user will not be able to scroll to it with the mouse wheel.

To unhide it, just do the reverse:

```
view->setRowHidden(row, false);
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
```

Comment: Works for me, small correction though, the re-enabling flags should be with binary "or": item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);

Comment: Were you using an editable combobox when seeing the issue with the scrollwheel?  On a non-editable combo just using view->setRowHidden(..) works fine.  Qt. 5.9.3

Comment: @Alchete Yes the combobox is editable, Qt 5.9.2 
Perhaps it was a bug in Qt 5.9.2 and fixed in Qt 5.9.3 (not able to test at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Althought there is no direct way to hide the item of the `QComboBox`, but you can use `QComboBox::setItemData` and set the size to (0,0) to hide the item of `QComboBox`:

```
comboBox->setItemData(row, QSize(0,0), Qt::SizeHintRole);
```

Comment: How do I make it visible again?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setVisible()` to alter the visibility of your object:

```
.setVisible(False) # Not Visible
.setVisible(True) # Visible
```

Comment: How do I access a comboBox item so I could set it to Visible(True) or (False)..?

Comment: I thought you meant the entire set of items in the box. I'm not sure an individual item can be hidden. What's wrong with removing out and adding it later?

Answer (score 0):

To show the item again:

```
comboBox->setItemData(row, QVariant(), Qt::SizeHintRole);
```

Note: changing the SizeHintRole doesn't work on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread after getting frustrated with a lack of hide functionality that would keep the item indexing etc.
I got it to work  based on @Kef and @CJCombrink answers. This is basically just a python translation.

I had a problem with qobject_cast.
Solved it by setting .setView(QListView()) to the QComboBox.

```
combo=QComboBox()
combo.setView(QListView())
```

hide:

```
combo.view().setRowHidden(rowindex,True)
tmp_item=combo.model().item(rowindex)
tmp_item.setFlags(tmp_item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

unhide:

```
combo.view().setRowHidden(rowindex,False)
tmp_item=combo.model().item(rowindex)
tmp_item.setFlags(tmp_item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
```

I decided to subclass the QComboBox and add the hide functionality. Bellow is an use example for testing.
You are welcome to use it. I make no assurances.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

#subclassed QComboBox with added hide row functionality
class ComboBox_whide(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setView(QListView())#default self.view() is a QAbstractItemView object which is missing setRowHidden, therefore a QListView needs to be set 
    def hide_row_set(self,row,value=True):
        """sets the row accesibility
        value=True hides the row"""
        self.view().setRowHidden(row,value)#hides the item from dropdown, however the item is stil accesible by moving down with arrow keys or mouse wheel. The following disables solves that
        tmp_item=self.model().item(row)
        if value:#hide -> disable
            tmp_item.setFlags(tmp_item.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        else:#enable
            tmp_item.setFlags(tmp_item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    def hide_row_toggle(self,row):
        """toggles the row accesibility"""
        if self.view().isRowHidden(row):#is hidden, therefore make available
            self.hide_row_set(row,False)
        else:#is not hidden, therefore hide
            self.hide_row_set(row,True)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        cwidg=QWidget()
        clayer=QVBoxLayout()
        cwidg.setLayout(clayer)
        self.setCentralWidget(cwidg)
        #button for testing
        self.btn=QPushButton('Button')
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        clayer.addWidget(self.btn)
        
        #subclassed QComboBox
        self.combo=ComboBox_whide()
        for n in range(3):#add 3 items with tooltips
            self.combo.addItem('item%i'%n)
            self.combo.setItemData(n,'tip%i'%n,Qt.ToolTipRole)
        clayer.addWidget(self.combo)
        
        #button test function - choose either or for testing
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        #uncomment for add/remove example self.btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_add_item)
        
    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.combo.hide_row_toggle(1)
    def remove_add_item(self):# here for naive comparison and to show why removing and adding is not ok
        if self.combo.count()==3:
            self.combo.removeItem(1)
        else:
            self.combo.addItem('new')#new "item1" withouth the ToolTip
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:#Pyside2 ipython notebook check
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: `qobject_cast` is only needed in C++ to downcast the generic `QAbstractItemView` type returned by the `->view()` to concrete imlementation (`QListView`), you don't need it in Python, just call `view()` on the combobox instance directly to get the desired `QListView` object instance.